# Trying to insert linebreaks within php variable

Tags: php

Please bear with me as I'm still very new to this. I'm simply trying to ensure the email message body below has linebreaks where I  put `<br/>`. However when I run the script the message body displays exactly as it is in the script even though it works perfectly in the editor I used to compose this email at Stackoverflow.

I realize its something very small and subtle. /n also didnt seem to work. Thanks for your help! I'm not sure i understand how to use  nl2br in my particular context. Again thanks for your patience and help.

```
$subject=" You're exclusive guide is only a click away!"; 
$message="Thanks for subscribing .$name! <br/> Click below to confirm your email and email and access your guide <br/> http://acmecorp.net/guide <br/> Acmecorp.net <br />Phone: 800-123-4468";
$headers = 'From:AcmeCorp<info@acmecorp.net>';
mail( $email, $subject, $message,$headers );`
```

Comment: If you use text email, HTML-style linebreaks will not work. Use `"\n"`instead.

Comment: its not /n, it's \n.  But in PHP you can actually just press enter and the parser will put it in for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute `<br/>` with "\n":

```
$subject=" You're exclusive guide is only a click away!"; 
$message="Thanks for subscribing .$name! \n Click below to confirm your email and email and access your guide \n http://acmecorp.net/guide \n Acmecorp.net \nPhone: 800-123-4468";
$headers = 'From:AcmeCorp<info@acmecorp.net>';
mail( $email, $subject, $message,$headers );`
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use HTML tags in a mail obviously. So, you have to send your mail in HTML, by adding a content type revelant in the headers.

Just before your `mail()` call, add `$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";` to have something like this:

```
$subject = " You're exclusive guide is only a click away!"; 
$message = "Thanks for subscribing .$name! <br/> Click below to confirm your email and email and access your guide <br/> http://acmecorp.net/guide <br/> Acmecorp.net <br />Phone: 800-123-4468";
$headers = 'From:AcmeCorp<info@acmecorp.net>';
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: This was going to be my next question and you anticipated it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: I wish I could accept more than one answer! I highly appreciate the help.